# Docker commit crashes terminal

Tags: docker, containers, commit

So I have a container, installed what I wanted etc. and now I have a game server container. What I want to do is to commit the changes but when I run `sudo docker commit 596e043d2d8a csgoserver` or `sudo docker commit 596e043d2d8a` the terminal asks for my password and after that there is no more feedback. Nothing I write in the terminal has any effect. When I reopen ssh and attach to the container (name hasn't changed) everything I have done is still there. Now I'm not sure if the changes have been commited and I don't wanna take chances here. How should I go about commiting changes?

Comment: you need to enter you root password, and when you commit, usually you add a tag like `docker commit 797 me/myimage:v4`  then it is easier to use the commited container

Comment: Note that commiting a container can take a while, depending on how much differences there is between the parent layer and the size of it. it also depends on the fs driver used (aufs, devicemapper, ..)